# Simplifying and Computing the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi all I would like to take compute the limit of the following in order to help me find the convergence:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{10}\cdot 3^{-(n+1)}}{n^{10}\cdot3^{-n}}$$

When I take the limit as the function goes to infinity I get $\frac{1}{3}$ but wolfram gives me $0$ from taking the limit of the attached image: [wolfram computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qH3L.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're right. Perhaps you mistyped the expression?

Comment: Limit as n approaches what? If you're looking for the limit as n->+/- infinty you're correct; it is 1/3. You must have misentered the equation into Wolfram.

Comment: Typing this expression into Wolfram gives me 1/3. 

(n+1)^10*3^-(n+1) / (n^10 * 3^(-n))


You are right with the 1/3

Comment: Thank you everyone. What I'm trying to do is understand convergence. The function is actually
$$n^{10} \cdot 3^-n$$
using the formula formula $\lim \n\to\inf \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ gives me the equation above. Does this mean the convergence is linear since the result is less than 1?

Answer (score 0):

simplifying we obtain $$\frac{(n+1)^{10}\cdot3^{-n}\cdot 3^{-1}}{n^{10}\cdot 3^{-n}}=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{10}$$

Comment: Thank you Dr. Sonnhard. What I'm trying to do is understand convergence. The function is actually
$$n^{10} \cdot 3^-n$$
using the formula formula \lim \n\to\inf \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} gives me the equation above. Does this mean the convergence is linear since the result is less than 1?